# Facebook graph API, get all ad accounts

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I have facebook app.
There is user id and access token of a user, who has granted ads_management and ads_read permission.
How can I get a list of all ad accounts, associated with that user?

Would be crazy happy to see solution in php.
Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use the `/adaccounts` endpoint.

If you're using the php SDK, this would work. I used `me` as the ID here. You would change that to the account ID of the user(s) you manage ads for.

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/me/adaccounts'
);

$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */
```

otherwise, port this CURL request to PHP:

```
curl -i -X GET \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/me/adaccounts?access_token="<ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

I suggest using the graph [API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) to experiment, if you dont already.

Comment: Using the Java SDK, you can do new User("me", context).getAdAccounts().execute()

Comment: That will give the ad accounts with id only. How to get a list of ad accounts with the id and name of the account?